# Update changes made to model Element(jlist) to mysql database, issue

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

please keep in mind i am an amateur. for some reason the code only works if there are only more then one elements in the jlist USING NETBEANS the error is somewhere in generated code.

this is the error i get :

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1

// this is my save button, the problem is when i try to save **// voor ledenlijst**

```
private String input ;
Mainn main;
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
int selectie;

 private void opslaanActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        String leiderString = leider.getText();
        String namen = model.get(1).toString();
        String codev = code.getText();
        String naam1 = model.get(selectie).toString();


        main = new Mainn();
        try {

            //voor leider wijzigen
            main.stat = main.con.prepareStatement("UPDATE project SET leider=? WHERE code = ?");
            main.stat.setString(1, leiderString);
            main.stat.setString(2, codev);


            // voor ledenlijst PROBLEM IS HERE
            main.stat2 = main.con.prepareStatement("UPDATE leden SET naam = ? WHERE naam = ?");
            main.stat2.setString(1, input);
            main.stat2.setString(2, naam1);




            main.stat.execute();
             main.stat2.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "opgeslagen");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);


        }


    }
```

// below is the code where the changes are made:

```
private void wijzigActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    //try {
    // } catch (SQLException ex) {
    //    System.out.println(ex);
    // }
    //  

  selectie = uitvoerLeden.getSelectedIndex();
  input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wijzig dit project lid", model.elementAt(selectie));
  model.setElementAt(input,selectie);  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At what point is `model` being initialized? I guess it's not before executing this line, where the error is probably occuring.

```
 String namen = model.get(1).toString();
```

Comment: haha nevermind, sorry your line did point to my mistake though. i didnt need that variable, unused i am so messy. thanks mate

Comment: @user1880803: you need to show which line throws the exception. Not to do so will hamper our ability to help you. 1+ to mtk for a decent guess at the solution.